# rails haml syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting $end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax, haml

I am getting a syntax error on my post partial view

```
.row-fluid{ :style => "margin:auto;"}
%span{:style => "display:inline-block"}
    .row
        %h5{:style => "display:inline-block"}= link_to user.username, user_posts_path(user)
        -if post.from_id
            %i.icon-small.icon-refresh{:style => "display:inline-block"}
            %h5{:style => "display:inline-block"}=link_to User.find(post.from_id).username, user_posts_path(User.find(post.from_id))
        -if post.source_id && post.source_id != post.user_id
            %h5.offset4{:style => "display:inline-block"} Source:
            %h5{:style => "display:inline-block"}= link_to User.find(post.source_id).username, user_posts_path(User.find(post.source_id))
        -if authenticateOwnership(user.id)
            =link_to "", user_post_path(user,post)
                %i.icon.icon-trash
    %li.thumbnail
        %a.thumbnail
            %img{ :src => "/uploads/#{@user.username}/#{post.id}/image",:style => "display:block; max-width:600px"}
        .caption
            %blockquote{:style => "margin:10 10 10 20"}
            %p= " " + post.content
```

After some digging the troublesome lines appear to be

```
-if authenticateOwnership(user.id)
    =link_to "", user_post_path(user,post)
        %i.icon.icon-trash
```

Here is my authenticateOwnership method(application controller)

```
def authenticateOwnership(userid)
  if currentuser.id != userid
   return false
  end
return true
end
```

If i remove the link_to tag it works as expected with no errors

Answer (score 3):

You surely meant:

```
- if authenticateOwnership(user.id)
  = link_to user_post_path(user,post) do
    %i.icon.icon-trash
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know you had to pass a block to nest tags like that

Comment: It isn't about HAML, `link_to` is a ruby method, you can't nest within it as if it were a regular haml `%tag`.